# In C using pthreads, how do I get a certain thread to run until a certain value has been reached?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a sensor on a device that is reading measurements, and I want the current thread to stop executing once a certain threshold has been reached

Comment: Perhaps `if (*condtion*) pthread_exit();`?

Comment: Would I have another thread that is constantly checking for the condition and exits the other thread if that condition is true? I was thinking of doing that, but it causes me some other problems, is there another way?

Comment: It could be any thread.  If you want to quit the current thread use `pthread_exit`.  If you want to quit a different thread use `pthread_kill` and give it the thread ID to stop.

Comment: If I use pthread_exit where would I insert that line of code? It will never get to it if it's at the end of the thread, because the thread isn't supposed to stop executing until the sensor reads that measurement

Comment: You would put it at the point you want the thread to stop, i.e. when you detect the exit condition.

Comment: there is no specific point in the thread that i want it to stop, it should only stop once that condition is true, it will keep running until it reaches the end, unless i put in if statements in between each line

Comment: If your thread has some sort of main loop then do the check on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Can share the structure of the 'current thread' ? is there processing loop ? does it wait for input/events, calculate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by two ways:

- Polling
- Interrupt

How to pool is explained by @dbush in the comments of the question.

To generate an interrupt you can use `__interrupt` keyword which is a compiler attribute. 
But , I feel polling will be convenient as explained by @dbush